# ASP.NET identity use email instead of user name

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

How can I use email instead of user name in the new ASP.NET identity system?

I tried to change the `RegisterViewModel` class:

```
[Display(Name = "Email address")]
[Required(ErrorMessage = "The email address is required")]
[EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "Invalid Email Address")]
public string UserName { get; set; }
```

but when I enter an mail adress I am getting the error:

```
User name fsdfsd@fsdfsd.de is invalid, can only contain letters or digits.
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You have 2 options to solve it by either turning off that validator, or create your own [UserValidator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972961.aspx).

You could turn it off like this:

```
UserManager.UserValidator = new UserValidator<TUser>(UserManager) 
                                    { 
                                       AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = false 
                                    };
```

Comment: I suggest creating a custom UserManager (e.g. AppUserManager : UserManager) that sets the UserValidator of itself in this way when instantiated. I do this so that I don't have to remember setting the UserValidator when newing up a UserManager class, and only have to remember to use my custom AppUserManager class.