# Issue with username validation message in asp.net identity

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-membership, asp.net-identity

I am using new membership system asp.net identity in my project. I want to use Email address as an Username and yes i have looked these questions already:

[Configure Microsoft.AspNet.Identity to allow email address as username](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19460078/configure-microsoft-aspnet-identity-to-allow-email-address-as-username)

[ASP.NET identity use email instead of user name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19758575/asp-net-identity-use-email-instead-of-user-name)

and i know how to use email as a Username.But i have another issue, the Validation error message:

*`Name xxxxxxxxx@xxxx.com is already taken.`*

this message comes when user try to register with existing email address.So instead of this error message i want to give error message some like:

*`User with the given email address already exist.`*

So how can i do this in Asp.Net identity ??

Answer (score 11):

Its just replacing the message. Search for the "Name {0} is already taken." and replace it with your message "User with the given email address already exists".

You can do it in AddError method. *This is an example, you shall create application specific working code.*

```
private void AddErrors(IdentityResult result)
{
    foreach (var error in result.Errors)
    {
        if (error.EndsWith("is already taken."))
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "User with the given email address already exists");
        else ModelState.AddModelError("", error);
    }
}
```

Comment: This works but it's not elegant. I believe the ASP.NET Identity team is working on the real code - source here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19962202/687549

Answer (score 2):

Another option would be to plug in your own UserValidator that only does the user name/email check, if it doesn't fail, it delegates to the default UserValidator, otherwise it returns an IdentityResult with the error message you want.