# How to change special ASP .NET MVC Model validation error text

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation

In many cases I can set validation error text directly in the Model (ErrorMessage). But in case of MVC Authentication there are some error texts I can't find anywhere in the Project. For instance the error text when user tries to register the user name which is already taken. In this case the error message is: "Name {username} is already taken." I cant find out where can I change this text.

Comment: can you tell what kind of authentication do you use? there are several approaches and libraries

Comment: Individual User Accounts. I let VS to create the logic for me when I create new ASP .NET MVC solution. I am quite new in this, so..

Comment: It's likely to be the error message that's coming out of AspNet Identity.  Check the Register post action and see what happens with the result of any call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have flag your question as duplicate because there is another such question. I'm not sure what the Administrators will do but you can check this topic: [How to localize ASP.NET Identity UserName and Password error messages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19961648/how-to-localize-asp-net-identity-username-and-password-error-messages/19962202#19962202)

And also this one could be helpful: [Issue with username validation message in asp.net identity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20452352/issue-with-username-validation-message-in-asp-net-identity)