# How to change the greeting message on ASP.Net from UserName to First Name or any other field?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, asp.net-identity

How can I change the below mentioned code to show: Hello "First Name" instead of Hello "UserName".

I have already created some custom fields inside my Identity user table such as "FirstName","MiddleName","LastName".

### Below mentioned code is inside Site.Master.

```
<li>
  <a runat="server" href="~/Account/Manage" title="Manage your account">
     Hello, <%: Context.User.Identity.GetUserName()  %> !
  </a>
</li>
```

I appreciate your efforts in reaching a solution for my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First Add `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin` namespace in `web.config`

```
<configuration>
   <namespaces>
       <!-- other namespaces -->
       <add namespace="Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin"/>
  </namespaces>
</configuration>
```

then replace your code with:

```
<li>
    <a runat="server" href="~/Account/Manage" title="Manage your account"> Hello,
        <%: HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext()
            .GetUserManager<YourNamespace.ApplicationUserManager>()
            .FindById(Context.User.Identity.GetUserId()).FirstName %>!
   </a>
</li>
```

Comment: Awesome solution <3 ... Thank you

Answer (score 3):

You will have to typecast the identity to the custom identity you made.. So you can use the field you used there. The code would look like this:

```
<li>
  <a runat="server" href="~/Account/Manage" title="Manage your account">
     Hello, <%: ((YourIdentity)Context.User.Identity).FirstName  %> !
  </a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name
```

It should work
Or you should try

```
User.Identity.Name
```