# How to login with "UserName" instead of "Email" in MVC Identity?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-identity

I need to set my login to use username instead of email address, how can I change it?

Comment: Please check this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27501533/use-username-instead-of-email-for-identity-in-asp-net-mvc5

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It's actually using the e-mail address as the username, so in the ASPNetUsers table, you'll see both the username and email fields with the email address.

Go into the AccountController, look for Register method (POST).

Change this:

```
var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email};
```

to this:

```
var user = new ApplicationUser
            {
                UserName = model.UserName,
                Email = model.Email
            };
```

Then go into the Login.cshtml and change all corresponding e-mail model fields to username instead.

Finally, go into the Login method (POST) in the AccountController and change model.Email to model.UserName.

```
var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.UserName, model.Password, 
             model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
```

You also have to make changes in AccountViewModels.cs in order to introduce your new UserName property.

Comment: Thanks Jason. The problem is when I type `model.UserName` I get the red underline and even when I type `model.` I don't see the UserName option to select.

Comment: @kevinMaxwell if you decide to use username, why dont you just modify ApplicationUser Model ?

Comment: @KevinMaxwell nah, The application user model

Comment: @codebrain I don't have any model under this name. :(

Comment: @codebrain Go into the AccountViewModels under the Models folder, look for LoginViewModel and you'll need to add a UserName property in there.  You'll also have to do the same to the RegisterViewModel.  It's definitely a lot to take in but practice is key!

Comment: @KevinMaxwell In RegisterViewModel.cs change the property `Email` to `UserName` , remove the [EmailAddress] annotation from there and change the `[Display(Name = "Email")]` to `[Display(Name = "Login")]` or something you want to display. If you want to keep `Email` property, then add `UserName` property to the same view model and make it as required.

Comment: I did what you wrote here, but I am receiving the message "Email cannot be null or empty." even if it is not in the form. I removed the attribute of Required from the RegisterViewModel and the AccountViewModel. Any ideas?

Comment: I answered myself accidentally ... I saw something that reads "RequireUniqueEmail = true" in the manager.UserValidator in ApplicationUserManager inside the class ApplicationUserManager in the IdentityConfig.cs. Change that to "false" and now I can complete the registration.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you do it

```
 var user = await _userManager.Users
           .FirstOrDefaultAsync(u => u.UserName == username || u.Email == username); 
 if (user != null){
    var result = await _signInManager
                .PasswordSignInAsync(/*email*/user.Email, password, false, false);
    /*removed for brevity*/
 }
```

Think you have a user having username=`test` and email=`myemail@example.com` then you would like to allow users to authenticate using test instead of myemail@...            `

PS. While the answer from @Jason works, sometimes you'd like to authenticate a user with  real username and password, not using the email.

In this case use my answer