# Using ASP.NET Identity with web forms- how to validate with username instead of email

Tags: c#, asp.net

This is a more specific post of an earlier question. I have seen a number of posts with answers on this issue and *none have worked for those who asked the question.*

The question is, using .NET Identity, how does one use the username for validation on a web form (Not MVC)  instead instead of the email address which is the default. I could post some code but honestly I am not exactly sure what class or method to post.

If you can answer this question kudos to you because no one else can figure it out.

Comment: what do you mean? email address can be confirmed by sending a code whereas your username might be known for someone else

Comment: True, email is used in two step authentication. However in certain marketing applications the data need not be as secure as say PayPal or Target. In these instances some users are scared off by having to enter their email address fearing loads of spam.  However they may be fine with entering a made up user name. Make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking into things like creating a custom sign in manager (To do this with MVC see http://www.jamessturtevant.com/posts/ASPNET-Identity2.0-Custom-Database/) and viewing answers to this question for MVC ( See [How to login with "UserName" instead of "Email" in MVC Identity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33069201/how-to-login-with-username-instead-of-email-in-mvc-identity)), it turns out that the answer is embarrassingly simple.
 
The Steps are as follows.
Modify Register.aspx and Login.aspx
On both pages create a UserName form control. Note that the field UserName already exists in the database so you do not have to add it.  Just copy the current email form control and paste the copy back into the form. Then on the new form control change the following.
1. Change Email to UserName everywhere it appears in the new form control
2. Change ID="Email" to ID="UserName"
 
3. Change TextMode="Email" to TextMode="singleline" 
4. Comment out the RequiredFieldValidator control that follows:
    RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="Email"
     CssClass="text-danger" ErrorMessage="The email field is required."

On Register.aspx.cs:
 
Change var user = new ApplicationUser() { **UserName = Email.Text**, Email = Email.Text };
To
var user = new ApplicationUser() { **UserName = UserName.Text**, **Email = string.IsNullOrEmpty(Email.Text)? "xxx@x.com" : Email.Text** }; (This is a bit of a hack but it works.)

On Login.aspx.cs 
Change 
var result = signinManager.PasswordSignIn(**Email.Text**, Password.Text, RememberMe.Checked, shouldLockout: false);
To
var result = signinManager.PasswordSignIn(**UserName.Text**, Password.Text, RememberMe.Checked, shouldLockout: false);

On IdentityConfig.cs
Change 
RequireUniqueEmail = **true**
To
RequireUniqueEmail = **false**