# Register using username instead of Email in ASP.NET MVC 5?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I have changed the `RegisterViewModel` to use `Username` instead of `Email` and omitted the email part when initialized `new ApplicationUser` in the `Register` POST method:

```
       public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Username/*, Email = model.Username*/ };
...
```

But when I register by username I get the error:

> Email cannot be null or empty.

How can I solve this, and is there a way to not allow identical usernames?

Comment: Check your code for any other places that the email variable is used and change them accordingly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use Username instead of Email for identity in Asp.net mvc5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27501533/use-username-instead-of-email-for-identity-in-asp-net-mvc5)

Answer (score 0):

you can change your RegisterViewModel  to

```
public class RegisterViewModel 
{
    [Remote("IsUserNameExist", "User", "", ErrorMessage = "this username exist", HttpMethod = "POST")]
    public string UserName { set; get; }
    //todo: other fileds......

}
```

and write your exist validation actionresul in your UserController

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [OutputCache(Location = OutputCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true,  Duration = 0, VaryByParam = "*")]
    public virtual JsonResult IsUserNameExist(string userName)
    {
        var check = _userService.CheckUserNameExist(userName);
        return check ? Json(false) : Json(true);
    }
```