# How to change user login credentials in identity asp.net mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I'm new in MVC and working on User Authentication Authorization.
I want to change user login credential with UniqueNumber instead of Email.

I tried but it throws this error

> **Error   1 :**   The best overloaded method match for 'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(string, string, bool, bool)' has some invalid arguments

**Login Action**

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(model);
        }

        // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
        // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, change to shouldLockout: true
        var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.UniqueNumber, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
        switch (result)
        {
            case SignInStatus.Success:
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
                return View("Lockout");
            case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
                return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = model.RememberMe });
            case SignInStatus.Failure:
            default:
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
                return View(model);
        }
    }
```

**LoginViewModel**

```
public class LoginViewModel
{

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Unique Number")]
    public int UniqueNumber { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Remember me?")]
    public bool RememberMe { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: At first look, UniceNumber is an int, but PasswordSignInAsync is expecting a string

Comment: @GonzaloLorieto Yes, but can I change if want to use a **Int value** instead of **Email or UserName** for Login?

Comment: you can, but you must call UniqueNumber.ToString(). Is it working now?

Comment: Thanks Sir @GonzaloLorieto problem solved. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering this question may be a duplicate of this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27501533/use-username-instead-of-email-for-identity-in-asp-net-mvc5):

You must change the registration of the users to use the `UniqueNumber` instead of the email when calling: `var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.UniqueNumber, Email = model.Email };`.

And yes, as @Gonzalo Lorieto said you must cast the `UniqueNumber` to string.

Comment: Is their any way to use int value instead of string