# Using Identity Username already exists using Identity MVC C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, error-handling, identity

I am using ASP.NET Identity and want to check only if username already exists. But it check email as well and gives error for both (Email and Username). I want to check only Username. How i can do it.
Below is the error. 
**Name customer@test.com is already taken.**
**Email customer@test.com is already taken.**
It should show only one statement either email or name.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Why don't you post your code?

Comment: can you follow the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27501533/use-username-instead-of-email-for-identity-in-asp-net-mvc5) and let me know if it works

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript to validate on lose focus of the username field. Here is an easy example for reference https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1104856/Validate-Email-ID-in-ASP-NET-TextBox-using-JavaScr

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am using Identity and it is functionality of Identity to avoid duplication user name / email. I want to use that but only for username not email.